# How to replace pipe delimited to white space in a specific range of columns?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, awk, sed

I have use awk and sed to replace pipe with white space, here's my code:

```
awk -F "|" -v OFS=" " ' $1=$1 '
sed "s/|/ /g" try.log
```

But it deletes all the pipe in my data. Here's a sample data:

```
JAP|09|7777|TECHNOLOGY|AGRICULTURE|INDUSTRY
```

The result I want is this:

```
JAP 09 7777|TECHNOLOGY|AGRICULTURE|INDUSTRY
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the first column always have 2 `|` you want to remove?

Comment: With GNU sed, try `sed -r "s/^([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|/\1 \2 /g"`

Comment: Yes, it always have a "|" after the 1st and 2nd column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one liner awk:

```
awk -F"|" '{a=""; for (i=1;i<=NF; i++)if(i <=3) a=a " "$i; else a=a "|"$i; sub("^[ ]","",a); print a}'
```

Long format:

```
BEGIN {
FS="|";
}
{
    a="";
    for (i=1; i<= NF; i++)
    {
        if (i <= 3)
        {
            a=a " "$i;
        }
        else
        {
            a=a "|"$i;
        }
     }
     sub("^[ ]","",a);
     print a;
}
```

Output:

```
echo "JAP|09|7777|TECHNOLOGY|AGRICULTURE|INDUSTRY" | awk -f script.awk
JAP 09 7777|TECHNOLOGY|AGRICULTURE|INDUSTRY
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -pe '$c = 0; s/\|/ /, $c++ while $c < 2'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/|/ /;s// /' file
```

A programmatic solution might be:

```
sed 'y/|/\n/;s/\n/|/3g;y/\n/ /' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/\|09\|/," 09 ")}1' file 
JAP 09 7777|TECHNOLOGY|AGRICULTURE|INDUSTRY
```